# Cryptofinance plugin pulling wrong data for KNC

Tags: cryptofinance

Seems there are two "KNC" tags on Coinmarketcap... Kyber Network and KingN Coin. Any idea how I should pull the Kyber Network data using this plugin? Right now it's pulling the KingN Coin info...

Answer (score 1):

There are over 60 coins out there that share the same symbol. You would have to use the full name of the coin to pull the data instead of ticker. According to the [documentation](https://cryptofinance.ai/docs/getting-started-with-cryptofinance/):

> To find the coin full name, simply go to its CoinMarketCap page and copy its name from the URL. For instance Cosmos URL is https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/cosmos/ so we’ll copy cosmos

However, you need to keep the quote currency in symbol. So if you are getting the data of Kyber Network in terms of bitcoin, you will have to use `=CRYPTOFINANCE("kyber-network/btc")`